# how to make div in bottom inside the main div?

Tags: html, css

how to make div with class boxLinks = bottom in the main box = class = main-box?

my idea

this class main width 1200px;
this class main-box are 5 div, every div width 25%

```css
.main-box {
  width= "25%";
  float= left;
}
```

```html
<div class= "main">
    <div class="main-box">
       <div class="boxImg"></div>
       <div class="boxTital"></div>
       <div class="boxLinks">
         <button> PRESS </button>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want this div boxLinks in the last div,

Comment: can u share a your code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.main-box {
    width= 25%;
    float= left;
    position:relative;
    min-height:150px;
    background:#000;
}

.boxLinks{
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   left:50%;
   transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class= "main">
    <div class="main-box">
       <div class="boxImg"></div>
       <div class="boxTital"></div>
       <div class="boxLinks">
         <button> PRESS </button>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, this code come with me but i have some problem with button is not come center in div boxLinks, i use text-align: center; and margin: 0;

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flexbox` to do the work.
You have to set your main-box as `flex`.
then the `boxLinks` become a `flex element`, so with the properti `align-self` you can put it at the bottom.

You can fin a good tutorial on [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.main-box {
  width: "25%";
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
}

.boxLinks {
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  height: 100px; 
  background: #000;
  align-self: flex-end;/* this do the work */
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main-box">
    <div class="boxImg"></div>
    <div class="boxTital"></div>
    <div class="boxLinks">
      <button> PRESS </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple. You can use `position: relative` on 'main-box' and `position: absolute`, `bottom:0` on 'boxLinks'.

Working example on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63rfv2xh/).

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.main-box {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f00;
}

.boxLinks {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main-box">
    <div class="boxImg"></div>
    <div class="boxTital"></div>
    <div class="boxLinks">
      <button> PRESS </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```